# how to get image file name using view pager in android

Tags: android, android-image

i am new to android. i seen one code from internet for displaying images stored on sdcard in full screen. it is working fine for me.images from my photo folder in sdcard are displaying and are sliding well. now i want to save image file name in sqlite.but i am not able to get image file name. if any one will please help me .
my code  for Activities are as....
FullScreenViewActivity.java

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity{

private Utils utils;
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
Button save;
ArrayList<String>path=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());
    //save.clearAnimation();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
            utils.getFilePaths());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name="";
            try{
            name=utils.getFileName();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //for(int i=0;i<path.size();i++)
            //{
                //sb.append(path.get(i).toString());
            //  name=path.get(i).toString();
            //}
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String name=utils.getResources().getResourceName(R.id.pager);
            path=utils.getFilePaths();

            return false;
        }
    });

    //String name=getResources().getResourceName(position);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

GridViewActivity.java

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

private Utils utils;
private ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
private GridView gridView;
private int columnWidth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    utils = new Utils(this);

    // Initilizing Grid View
    InitilizeGridLayout();

    // loading all image paths from SD card
    imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();

    // Gridview adapter
    adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, imagePaths,
            columnWidth);

    // setting grid view adapter
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void InitilizeGridLayout() {
    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

    gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
    gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
            (int) padding);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
}

}
```

FullScreenImageAdapter.java

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private Context c;
private Utils utils;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths; 
private LayoutInflater inflater;
String name="";

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    //utils=new Utils(this);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    Button btnClose;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
   // btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    //name=""+imgDisplay.getId();
    // close button click event

    /*  btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //_activity.finish();
            //Toast.makeText(c, "kkkk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }); 


    btnClose.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(buttonView.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(c, "kkkk", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    */

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}

}
```

GridViewImageAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private int imageWidth;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
        int imageWidth) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._filePaths = filePaths;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._filePaths.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this._filePaths.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // get screen dimensions
    Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
            imageWidth);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    // image view click listener
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

    return imageView;
}

class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // on selecting grid view image
        // launch full screen activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        _activity.startActivity(i);
    }

}

/*
 * Resizing image size
 */
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
    try {

        File f = new File(filePath);

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale *= 2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

pojo class AppConstant

```
public class AppConstant {

// Number of columns of Grid View
public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 3;

// Gridview image padding
public static final int GRID_PADDING = 8; // in dp

// SD card image directory
//@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "/SD card/kul_pics/";

// supported file formats
public static final List<String> FILE_EXTN = Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg",
        "png");
}
```

ImageView class TouchImageView.java

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            final CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(getContext());
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(curr);
                start.set(last);
                cb.setChecked(false);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                            origWidth * saveScale);
                    float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                            origHeight * saveScale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                    fixTrans();
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
```

pojo class Utils.java

```
public class Utils {

private Context _context;
static String filePath="";

// constructor
public Utils(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

/*
 * Reading file paths from SDCard
 */
public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myphoto");
                    //+ File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

    // check for directory
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        // Check for count
        if (listFiles.length > 0) {

            // loop through all files
            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                // get file path
                 filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                // check for supported file extension
                if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                    // Add image path to array list
                    filePaths.add(filePath);
                }

            }
        } else {
            // image directory is empty
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                            + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.show();
    }

    return filePaths;
}

/*
 * Check supported file extensions
 * 
 * @returns boolean
 */
private boolean IsSupportedFile(String filePath) {
    String ext = filePath.substring((filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1),
            filePath.length());

    if (AppConstant.FILE_EXTN
            .contains(ext.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

/*
 * getting screen width
 */
public int getScreenWidth() {
    int columnWidth;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }
    columnWidth = point.x;
    return columnWidth;
}
public String getFileName() throws IOException{
    getFilePaths();
    File directory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myphoto");
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        // getting list of file paths
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
    // loop through all files
        if (listFiles.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

        // get file path
         filePath = listFiles[i].getCanonicalPath();//getAbsolutePath();
    }
        }
    }
    return filePath;
}
}
```

in my FullScreenViewActivity class i want to get name of image file but every time it is showing same image name even after sliding images.

Comment: there is no such method getName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a TextView in **layout_fullscreen_image.xml** and give it id as **filename_textView**

Update **FullScreenImageAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
TouchImageView imgDisplay;
TextView fileNameTextView;
Button btnClose;

inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
        false);

imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
fileNameTextView=viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.filename_textView);
File newFile=new File(_imagePaths.get(position));
String fileName=newFile.getName();//contains file name
fileNameTextView.setText(fileName);
 btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(c, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: image name should change when i slide..but it is showing same image name for every image...........there must be some way out

Comment: make a textview on your adapter class under getView() method and set its text to file name.

Comment: there is no method getView() in adapter class..if i use TextView in adapter class...it is forcefully stopped

Comment: Where do you want image name- on GridView or FullScreen View.

Comment: in fullscreenview  when i click save button i want to display image name in Toast. so that i can save that name in sqlite

Comment: thanks...it is showing image name... but i used my button infullscreen_view.xml....so how i can get image name there by clcking that button

Comment: plz post your xml file

Comment: I have updated my answer to display a toast containing file name on a button click. Try that ..

Comment: @AnandPrakash can u please help me i have 3 buttons in my view and have view pager in center now i want to save image which is displaying in view pager by clicking in save button i am not getting where to write code to achieve this task .... and how will i get imagename from viewpager may i need towrite code in adapter ?